# React: Fire a function when the element is blurred

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fire a function when an element has loses focus, but it appears the blur event is not being recognized in my React app.  I'm unclear on what I'm missing.  The following snippet is just above the return method within my component.

My div carries the ref {infoWindow}.  At the moment, the console.log is not outputting anything when I click inside the div window and then out.

```
const infoWindow = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
if (infoWindow.current) {
  infoWindow.current.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
    console.log(`We've been blurred`);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think part of the component code might be helpful in this case. Did you use this ref on any element? Is this a functional component/class based component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you introduce side effects in React, adding an event listener to an element is a side effect, and side effects should be created inside a useEffect.

Here is the problem with your code

```
const infoWindow = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
// assume your component gets rendered once - at the initial render the component is not mounted in dom yet
// then infoWindow.current is null, and an event listener will not be added. This is what is probably happening with you.
// assume your component is rendered 1000 times, then you will add 999 event listeners, which is definitely not what you want
if (infoWindow.current) {
  infoWindow.current.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
    console.log(`We've been blurred`);
  });
}
```

The solution is to use useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (infoWindow.current) {
     const handler = (event) => {
       console.log(`We've been blurred`);
     }
     // notice that i get a reference to the element here, so i can safely use it in the clean function
     const element = infoWindow.current
     element.addEventListener('blur', handler);
     // this is a clean function that will be called to clear the side effects you just introduced
     return () => element.removeEventListener('blur', handler);

  }


}, [])
```

**EDIT**
What is mentioned above is correct, but you also have another problem, div elements do not receive focus events by default, and so wont blur. If you want an element to blur, and focus, then add tabIndex to it, so on your div do

```
<div tabIndex={0}>...</div>
```

Comment: I have this added to my code, but it does not fire the blur event either.  As soon as I click outside of the div, nothing happens.

Comment: I even tried using the "Force element state" events and clicked on :focus, but unclicking does nothing either.  This is just weird.

Comment: @pingeyeg this is not weird, div elements by default don't receive focus events, unless you add tabIndex to them - or make them contenteditable -, see my edit to solve your problem

Comment: so, I'm noticing that if I don't click inside the div element, the blur event will not fire.  This dev element will just have text inside so will probably never be clicked in, therefore I believe I need to fire a focus event once the div appears.

Comment: @pingeyeg well i have solved the issue in the question, but anyway it seems you are doing something incorrect with how you are trying to use the div, but thats out the scope of this question

Comment: Yeah, you are correct.  Thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add an `onBlur` event listener to the div?

https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#mouse-and-pointer-events

Comment: I tried that as well, but that still didn't fire anything.

Comment: Are you sure it's getting focused?